# Proof of Concept in agile development

Tags: agile, prototyping

I am part of a team that develops and maintains a B2B web portal that had evolved over several years. We follow an agile development process.

My department has plans for a major platform upgrade because of the non flexibility of the existing solution to our current needs and to conduct a POC for exploring the ideas. The aim of the POC is to have a model or prototype and a clear design blueprint for important technological choices and directions. Product owners would like to see some results within 2 months and there is budget for hiring the services of 2 developers for this period.

**My question is this:**

Is there a way to conduct a POC /prototyping work in an agile way (avoiding the trap of grant design blueprint which may not be the best choice in practice)? The questions which I have to answer are not simple ones - questions such as whether to use an RDBMS or a NoSql DB, whether to use a portal server like Liferay for user and content management or whether to build one of our own, whether to have different capabilities running as microservices for scalability reasons or plain old SOA is enough etc. etc.

Comment: You can avoid the "I searched but didn't find anything" wording in your questions.  It's not proof of prior research anyway; if you want to demonstrate that, then show us your actual research.

Comment: How is the usual approach (make something that works, have technical spikes to investigate candidates, expand based on end user feedback, etc) not sufficient for your needs (besides the whole **fixed deadline** thing)?

Comment: @Telastyn The aim of the POC is to avoid mistakes that are expensive to correct at a later stage - like technology or platform choices that involve licensing budget, hiring of new resources etc. I am not sure how an iterative approach that you hint will work. On the other hand, I feel a bit uneasy in doing just "design and prototype work" for at least 2 months

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't find any way to "show the actual research". When I type the subject, I already got a few suggestions on related topics, but none of them seem to address my question. I welcome your edit anyway

Comment: Check out the answers to [this previous question][1].


  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218568/how-does-rapid-prototyping-fit-into-an-agile-methodology

Comment: @DutchOven thanks! That was what I was looking for..

Comment: One would usually do a trade study first. Or, I suppose you can guess which products you might need and blindly go down that path in the hopes that you prove your choice would work.